# How would you decrease by one the value of a numeric column cell in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code, where I `decrease the quantity by one` if a user `buys` a `product`. Here the data is `stored in text files`.

Now my question is that how would I solve this **if data is stored in MySQL**.

Basically I want to `update the cell` by `subtracting 1` from its value. For example if `quantity = 200`, I want to update to `quantity = 199`.

```
for( $i = 0; $i < count( $ajProducts ) ; $i++ ) {
    if ( $sProductId == $ajProducts[$i]->id ) { 
        //check if the value of the id is equal to the value in the array.

        $ajProducts[$i]->quantity = $ajProducts[$i]->quantity-1;

        //increase the quanity of the object by one if there is a match ;
    } 
}
```

I have started with something like this: `UPDATE products SET quantityInStock=-1 WHERE productCode=':productCode`but it updates to `0` the `cell`.

Comment: please elaborate the question and it seems question need more tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply set the `quantityInStock = quantityInStock - 1` like this

```
UPDATE products SET quantityInStock=quantityInStock-1 WHERE productCode=':productCode
```